# Modifier condition always false

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum

I am passing an array of addresses into a contract from a parent contract. Using that I am generating a mapping with those address to quickly verify the msg.sender is part of the set mappings.

To check if a `msg.sender` is part of the mappings I am using the restricted modifier.

```
contract Upload{

    mapping(address => bool) managerAddresses;
    string public ownerName;
    string public location;

    modifier restricted(){
        require(managerAddresses[msg.sender]);
        _;
    }


    constructor(address[] _managerAddressesArr,string _ownerName,string _location)  public {
        for(uint i = 0;i<_managerAddressesArr.length;i++){
            managerAddresses[_managerAddressesArr[i]] = true;
        }
        ownerName = _ownerName;
    }

    function setLocation(string _location) restricted public{
        location = _location;
    }



}
```

But the setLocation function is unable to change the location when the restricted modifier is on and the transaction is mined but doesn't execte.
Even though the address passed by the managerAddressesArr are correct and without the modifier I can execute the functions.

Also solidity gives a

> Gas requirement of function Upload.setLocation(string) high:
>   infinite

Does anyone have any idea whats wrong with the restricted modifier?

Comment: Don't really know for your problem, but in your for loop, shouldn't it be i<=_manager instead of just <?

Comment: @Andromelus No because it's zero-based. OP: The warning is caused by your array - Solidity has no way of knowing how many elements are in it so it warns about possible gas requirement problems

Answer (score 0):

It seems to work just fine here. Try this: https://ethfiddle.com/1e8OhY-Czd

I deployed it with the first available address in the list (which is the sender) and, then called `setLocation` and then checked the getter of `location` - it had the right value.

Comment: @OP: Same for me. Everything works as expected.